# window.location.hostname results in t.sharethis.com why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running .NET site locally on localhost. When I run the command `window.location.hostname` I get t.sharethis.com. I have sharethis widget, but why this commands results in that text?

The URL is `http://localhost:54687/`

Update: When I remove the sharethis widget, I get `staticxx.facebook.com`.

Comment: What browser? Where do you run the command?

Comment: @Dekel I run it in Chrome

Comment: It's possible the widget is doing something tricky to fool the browser into allowing cross domain requests. We'd need to see more of your code to help you though

Comment: So does facebook, because when I remove the sharthis, I get the facebook one. Tricky bustards :)